# Javascript Assign function does not work

Tags: javascript, datatables

I have an application showing two datatables. Both tables use the button extension to support a column visibility dialog.
The second table has a first column without title. In the column visibility Dialog the button should have a title, that is why i override the columnText function of the colvis extension

```
var buttons= [{
    extend: 'colvis',
    postfixButtons: ['colvisRestore'],
    collectionLayout: 'fixed three-column'
}];
if("secondTable" === tableName) {
    buttons[0]['columnText'] = function (dt, idx, title) {
        if (idx === 0) {
            return "firstColumnTitle";
        } else {
            return title;
        }
    };
    //add default buttons to buttons
    buttons[0]['buttons'] = [{extend: 'columnsToggle'}];
    //add one extra button to the collection
    buttons[0]['buttons'].push([
    {
        extend: 'columnToggle',
        text: 'HR',
        columns: [1, 2]
    }]);
}
DataTable({
    rowId: 'id',
    ajax: 'content.do',
    buttons: buttons
});
```

I would expect to have the columntext function called for second table only

if i add buttons the `columnText` function is no longer called. Why?

Comment: `"secondTable" === tableName` is never `true`?

Comment: This should work, if the condition is true. After the `if("secondTable" === tableName) { ... }`, you may console the `buttons` variable and check the result.

Comment: "secondTable" === tablename is true. According to the chrome debugger(console.log shows the same) it looks the same either assigning the function on object creation or changing the value afterwards. Just the function location refers to a different line number.

Comment: I guess you are using an older version of ColVis, `columnText` was introduced in v1.3.0  (i.e recently)...

Comment: Or maybe the order of executing the code it's not the same as you posted here.

Comment: @davidkonrad: i am using v1.4.2 and as i said the feature is working fine, if i assign the function on object creation, it is just not working when adding it afterwards.

Comment: @Adelin: the order is like posted, i just cut of irrelevant datatable variables

Comment: There is nothing wrong with that concept -> **https://jsfiddle.net/2nwqa2jk/11/**

Comment: From what you posted there is no issue, so maybe what you cut is not as irrelevant as you may think.

Comment: @davidkonrad thanks for the fiddle. Adelin was right there was something not that irrelevant as expected. i added this to another fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/mo65fpj3/ and in the post above

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the comments above @davidkonrad and @Adelin. If found the reason.

instead of assigning the columnText function to the colvis extension, i need to assign it to the columnsToggle Extension inside.

```
if("secondTable" === tableName) {
  //add default buttons to buttons
  buttons[0]['buttons'] = [{
    extend: 'columnsToggle',
    columnText: function (dt, idx, title) {
    if (idx === 0) {
      return "firstColumnTitle";
    } else {
      return title;
    }
  }}];
  //add one extra button to the collection
  buttons[0]['buttons'].push([
  {
    extend: 'columnToggle',
    text: 'HR',
    columns: [1, 2]
  }]);
}
```